# Pod in status pending due to FailedScheduling - how to debug?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I've created a new pod by copy-pasting configuration (values.yaml, requirements.yaml, subchart) from other working pod (nginx app) and changing all names.
After redeploying my new pod is indefinitely in status pending, when I describe it it has following event:

```
 Type     Reason            Age        From               Message
  ----     ------            ----       ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  0/19 nodes are available: 19 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

That doesn't tell me much. How can I get more details to learn why scheduling failed exactly?

`deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "xyz.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "xyz.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "xyz.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "xyz.name" . }}
      release: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
      labels:
        app: {{ template "xyz.name" . }}
        release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      {{- if .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
{{ toYaml .Values.imagePullSecrets | indent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      volumes:
        - name: confd
          configMap:
            name: {{ template "xyz.fullname" . }}
            items:
              - key: resolver
                path: resolver.conf
        - name: nginx-config
          configMap:
            name: {{ template "xyz.fullname" . }}
            items:
              - key: nginxConf
                path: default
      containers:
        - name: {{ template "xyz.fullname" . }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
              name: confd
            - mountPath: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
              name: nginx-config
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 12 }}
          env:
          - name: XYZ_API_URL
            value: {{ .Release.Name }}-xyz-api
          {{- if .Values.environment }}
          {{- range $key, $value := .Values.environment }}
          - name: {{ toYaml $key }}
            value: {{ toYaml $value }}
          {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
{{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
```

`get no --show-labels`

```
NAME                   STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION   LABELS
k8s-app-stg-c1-01      Ready     <none>    328d      v1.16.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,esxcluster=app,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-app-stg-c1-01,kubernetes.io/os=linux,role=preemptible
k8s-app-stg-c1-02      Ready     <none>    328d      v1.16.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,esxcluster=app,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-app-stg-c1-02,kubernetes.io/os=linux,role=preemptible
k8s-app-stg-c1-03      Ready     <none>    328d      v1.16.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,esxcluster=app,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-app-stg-c1-03,kubernetes.io/os=linux,role=preemptible
k8s-app-stg-c1-04      Ready     <none>    297d      v1.16.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,esxcluster=app,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-app-stg-c1-04,kubernetes.io/os=linux,role=preemptible
k8s-app-stg-c1-05      Ready     <none>    297d      v1.16.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,esxcluster=app,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-app-stg-c1-05,kubernetes.io/os=linux,role=preemptible
k8s-app-stg-c1-06      Ready     <none>    24d       v1.16.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,esxcluster=app,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-app-stg-c1-06,kubernetes.io/os=linux,role=preemtible
k8s-bi-stg-c1-01       Ready     <none>    212d      v1.16.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,esxcluster=bi,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-bi-stg-c1-01,kubernetes.io/os=linux
k8s-ci-stg-c1-01       Ready     <none>    60d       v1.16.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,esxcluster=ci,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-ci-stg-c1-01,kubernetes.io/os=linux,role=preemtible
k8s-ci-stg-c1-02       Ready     <none>    41d       v1.16.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,esxcluster=ci,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-ci-stg-c1-02,kubernetes.io/os=linux,role=preemtible
k8s-ci-stg-c1-03       Ready     <none>    41d       v1.16.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,esxcluster=ci,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-ci-stg-c1-03,kubernetes.io/os=linux,role=preemtible
k8s-ci-stg-c1-04       Ready     <none>    41d       v1.16.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,esxcluster=ci,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-ci-stg-c1-04,kubernetes.io/os=linux,role=preemtible
k8s-master-stg-c1-01   Ready     master    1y        v1.16.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-master-stg-c1-01,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
k8s-master-stg-c1-02   Ready     master    1y        v1.16.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-master-stg-c1-02,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
k8s-master-stg-c1-03   Ready     master    1y        v1.16.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-master-stg-c1-03,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
k8s-svc-stg-c1-01      Ready     <none>    326d      v1.16.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,esxcluster=svc,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-svc-stg-c1-01,kubernetes.io/os=linux,role=preemptible
k8s-svc-stg-c1-02      Ready     <none>    325d      v1.16.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,esxcluster=svc,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-svc-stg-c1-02,kubernetes.io/os=linux,role=preemptible
k8s-svc-stg-c1-03      Ready     <none>    325d      v1.16.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,esxcluster=svc,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-svc-stg-c1-03,kubernetes.io/os=linux,role=preemptible
k8s-svc-stg-c1-04      Ready     <none>    297d      v1.16.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,esxcluster=svc,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-svc-stg-c1-04,kubernetes.io/os=linux,role=preemptible
k8s-svc-stg-c1-05      Ready     <none>    297d      v1.16.1   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,esxcluster=svc,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-svc-stg-c1-05,kubernetes.io/os=linux,role=preemptible
```

Comment: share your deployment file and output from command 'kubectl get no --show-labels'

Comment: How the did you deploy this pod? could you show the helm command and the value file.

Comment: Can you share your `values.yaml` and list node taints using this command: 
 `kubectl get nodes -o json | jq '.items[].spec.taints'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of 'esxcluster' OR role=preemptible label to schedule your workload to appropriate nodes. You might need to add node selector and toleration's to the values.yaml that you pass to helm install command

Comment: it worked after adding `esxcluster` toleration to the pod in values.yaml

Comment: The solution is worked for the user. This one should not have been down voted

Answer (score 1):

I think that the previous answer by @P-Ekambaram should be elaborated.

Your `pod` is in pending status because your nodes are not accepting it due to taints. 
`Taints` allow a node to repel a set of pods. Using tolerations 
you can schedule pods into node with matching taints.

Best quick example how taints work is simply create single node kubernetes cluster. 
In this case you are removing a `taint` from master node called `master:NoSchedule` 
This will allow you to schedule pods on the master node.

This is also very useful when you want to reserve some sets of nodes for specific purpose so you can schedule pods that require them.

Coming back to your error you have to add tolerations under the spec of your pod that matches those taints in order to have it scheduled.

You can list your taints using this command (`jq` is required to use it):

```
kubectl get nodes -o json | jq '.items[].spec.taints'
```

The tainted format looks like this:

```
`<key>=<value>:<effect>`
```

Where `<effect>` tell kubernetes scheduler what 
should happen to pod that don`t tolerate this taint.

Here is an example how those tolerations look in pod yamls:

```
tolerations:
- key: "key"
  operator: "Equal"
  value: "value"
```

Kubernetes documentation explains well [taints and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration).